# Looking for source to understand JSF code with the database insert & read

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I need your help in getting detailed examples about how I can read/insert into database using JSF code for its different components. I am a beginner in JSF and I have the basics, however, I need the best source which it has helpful, easy and detailed steps to understand the techniques for connecting to the DB and how to insert or read data from the database.

I tried to search, but I found the lessons are not helpful or not described in details. Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 1):

JSF is for the web/presentation tier. You *could* implement the db access in the managed bean (also web tier) through plain [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html), but I wouldn't recommend it.

You should separate the db access into the persistence tier. For that you can start off by looking at JPA for persistence and EJB for the business logic connecting the persistence tier and the web tier. There are other solutions, but I point out these two, because the tutorials are available at the [JavaEE tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm) site. You'll want to focus on [Part VII: Enterprise Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partentbeans.htm#BNBLR) and [PartVIII: Persistence](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partpersist.htm#BNBPY). The tutorial is a good place to start to learn JavaEE. There's a bunch of examples that can be run from the GlassFish server. As a bonus, all examples use JSF for the front end ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Interaction with databases has no relation with JSF web component based framework. You're searching instead for an Object Relational Mapping (ORM) framework to get started with. This is one of those framework: [Hibernate Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/).